# How is binary data related to double precision data?

Tags: matlab, audio

I am using `wavread` in MATLAB, which outputs the data in a .wav file in double precision. I am wondering how this relates to binary, such as 0's and 1's. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know much about Matlab's wavread, but double precision is a standard for describing a "floating point" value. That is, a value that always has the same number of (binary) digits of precision.

A double precision floating point number in binary looks like this: [image: Floating point diagram from wikipedia]

Each of those boxes represents a bit (short for "binary digit", or a 1 or a 0). It works like scientific notation: the exponent and fraction are both base-2 representations of numbers, and the number this represents is (with some exceptions for things like 0 and NaN) $$(-1)^{\text{sign}}\times 2^{\text{exponent - exponent bias}} \times 1.\text{fraction}$$

Where the "exponent bias" is there to allow you to represent negative exponents, and the "." in $1.\text{fraction}$ is a "binary point" instead of a decimal point.

You can read about the particulars of the double precision format [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), which is where I got the image and formula.

Comment: The specific int-to-float conversion factor used by matlab is discussed here: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2009/12/int-float-int-its-jungle-out-there.html

Comment: So if I am understanding this correctly, double precision type data is just is just a converted form of the typical 0's and 1's binary data, correct?

Comment: @BobbyDolan: It's not "converted". Double precision is a binary format. It *is* the typical ones and zeros binary data.

Answer (score 1):

Wavread scales it's output to be between -1 and 1. How the relates to your binary signal depends on its bit depth. You can return the bit depth when you read the file like so

`[y, Fs, nbits] = wavread(filename) %returns the number of bits per sample (nbits)`

To scale the signal you can then multiply by 2^(nbits-1). This will give you the decimal equivalent of the binary signal representation, which you can then convert, should you wish to.